# new quote-based environment end spacing

Tags: environments, punctuation, quoting

In order to insert quotations, the document uses a `quote`-based `\newenvironmentx`

```
\newenvironmentx{QUOTE}[1][1=.]{%
  \begin{quote}%
  \tiny\noindent%
  \gdef\parQ{#1}``%
}{\parQ''%
  \normalsize%
  \end{quote}%
}
```

The quotations should occur within `LaTex` quotes, and, by default, the last paragraph ends with dot.

Otherwise, when a citation is pointed out using `\cite`, the quotations are typeset as follows:

```
\begin{QUOTE}[~--~(\cite{etc}, pp.~2).]%
... is mainly implemented by means of ... systems%
\end{QUOTE}
```

so that I would expect `"... systems - ([1], pp. 2)."`, with just a space around the dash, hence the extra care to end lines with percent, to comment-out the newlines; instead, more spaces are put, and the result is something like `"... systems`    `- ([1], pp. 2)."`

How can I avoid the `\newenvironmentx{QUOTE}` not have the last character in its last paragraph immediately followed by (either default dot or) the binding space (tilde)?

**EDITED**

OK, this is the `mwe.dtx` wherefrom `mwe.cls` results by `latex mwe.ins`:

```
% \iffalse    (METACOMMENT)
%%
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
%% Document class `mwe' to use with LaTeX 2e.
%%
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
% \fi
%
% \CheckSum{370}
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
% ^^A \MakeShortVerb{\|}
% \section{Internals}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<class>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \iffalse (Don't show this in the doc).
%<*driver>
         \ProvidesFile{mwe.drv}
%</driver>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<class>\ProvidesClass{./mwe}
        [2013/03/29 v1.01
%<class>        MWE tex.stackexchange.com class]
%    \end{macrocode}
% \iffalse (Omitted from the doc)
%<*driver>
]
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \subsection{Driver for this document}
%
% The \dst{} program will extract the following driver from this file:
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\EnableCrossrefs
%\DisableCrossrefs % Say \DisableCrossrefs if index is ready
\RecordChanges
%\OnlyDescription % Comment out for implementation details
\CodelineIndex
\begin{document}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \raggedbottom
%    \begin{macrocode}
\IfFileExists{suffix.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{suffix}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The suffix package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The suffix package allows for starred commands.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{tokenizer.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage[trim]{tokenizer}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The tokenizer package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%
    The tokenizer package allows list processing.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{xkvltxp.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{xkvltxp}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xkvltxp package was not found.}{%%%%%
    The xkvltxp package is bound to xkeyval.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{xkeyval.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{xkeyval}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xkeyval package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xkeyval package will anyway be loaded implicitly.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{xargs.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{xargs}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xargs package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xargs package is mandatory with commands and environments.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{xifthen.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{xifthen}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xifthen package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xifthen package is needed for labels, references...%
  }}
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{macrocode}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@lst@nul}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@def@nul}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@lst@set}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@def@set}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@lst@add}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@lst@rem}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@lst@r@m}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@lst@pop}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@lst@p@p}
% initialize an empty list
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@nul[2][2=mwe@]{\mwe@lst@set{}{#1}[#2]}
% initialize empty definition macros
\let\mwe@def@nul\mwe@lst@nul
% create an empty list from a given list
\newcommandx%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mwe@lst@set[3][addprefix=\global,3=mwe@]{%%%%%%%%%%%
\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname#3#2\endcsname{#1}}
% initialize definition macros
\let\mwe@def@set\mwe@lst@set
% add item to the top of the list (replacement for \in@)
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@add[3][3=mwe@]{%
  \ifx\\#1\\\else\mwe@empt@if*{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{\@expandtwoargs%
    \mwe@lst@set{#1}{#2}[#3]}{\@expandtwoargs%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \mwe@lst@set{#1,\@nameuse{#3#2}}{#2}[#3]}\fi%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}
% remove specified item #1 from the in/out list #2
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@rem[3][3=mwe@]{%
  \ifx\\#1\\\else\mwe@NOT@empt@if{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{%
    \mwe@lst@r@m{#1}{#2}[#3]}\fi%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}
% helper for both above and below (employment of \@removeelement)
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@r@m[3][3=mwe@]{\@expandtwoargs%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \@removeelement{#1}{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{\mwe@v@r}\@expandtwoargs%
  \mwe@lst@set{\mwe@v@r}{#2}[#3]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}
% remove first item from the list #2 and save the item in command #1
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@pop[3][3=mwe@]{%
  \mwe@empt@if*{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{%
    \mwe@def@nul{#1}[#3]}{\@expandtwoargs%%%%%%%%%%%
    \mwe@lst@p@p{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{,}\@expandtwoargs%
    \mwe@lst@r@m{\mwe@var}{#2}[#3]\@expandtwoargs%%%
    \mwe@def@set{\mwe@var}{#1}[#3]}%
}
% helper for \mwe@lst@pop above (employment of \GetTokens)
\newcommand\mwe@lst@p@p[2]{\mwe@lst@get{#1#2}}
% get tokens from a list: head is \mwe@var; tail is \mwe@v@r
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@get[4]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[2=var,3=v@r,4=mwe@]{\GetTokens{#4#2}{#4#3}{#1}}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@empt@}
%    \begin{macrocode}
% positive \equal{}
\newtest\mwe@empt@[1]{\equal{#1}{}}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@NOT@if}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@NOT@empt@if}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@empt@if}
% \begin{macro}{\mwe@empt@if*}
%    \begin{macrocode}
% negative \ifthenelse to have it work with the above
\newcommand\utt@NOT@if[2]{\ifthenelse{#1}{}{#2}}
% derived \NOT if \equal{}
\newcommand\mwe@NOT@empt@if[2]{\mwe@NOT@if{\mwe@empt@{#1}}{#2}}
% positive \ifthenelse through \equal{}
\newcommand\mwe@empt@if[2]{\mwe@empt@if*{#1}{#2}{}}
% positive \ifthenelse through \equal{} (two branches)
\WithSuffix%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\mwe@empt@if*[3]{\ifthenelse{\mwe@empt@{#1}}{#2}{#3}}
% positive \ifthenelse through \equal
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\LoadClass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}[2007/10/19]
\IfFileExists{fontenc.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The fontenc package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The fontenc package is required for some fonts.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{inputenc.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The inputenc package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%
    The inputenc package provides UTF-8 unicode.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{multicol.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{multicol}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The multicol package was not found.}{%%%%%%%
    The multicol package is required in tables.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{multirow.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{multirow}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The multirow package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%
    The multirow package is required for tables.%
  }}
%    \end{macrocode}
%    \begin{macrocode}
% discern "enumerate" environments (true) from the rest (false)
\newif\if@mwe@some@that@\@mwe@some@that@false
% list of true|false values implemented as stack for \begin|\end
\mwe@lst@nul{some@bels}
% temporary store false or true popped off the \mwe@some@bels
\mwe@def@nul{some@bebl}
% save command \begin original (\LaTeX) definition
\let\mwe@begin\begin
% redefine \begin but invoke previous code
\def\begin{\mwe@some@mark\mwe@begin}
% save command \end original (\LaTeX) definition
\let\mwe@end\end
% redefine \end but invoke previous code
\def\end{\mwe@some@m@rk\mwe@end}
% push boolean value gotten from flag onto the "begin/end" stack-list
\newcommandx\mwe@some@mark[7][1=true,2=bels%%%%%%%%
,3=that,4=some@,5=mwe,6=@,7=false]{\@expandtwoargs%
\mwe@lst@add{\if@mwe@some@that@#1\else#7\fi}{#4#2}%
\expandafter\global\csname#6#5#6#4#3#6#7\endcsname}
% pop boolean value from the "begin/end" stack-list and set flag
\newcommandx\mwe@some@m@rk[6]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[1=bebl,2=bels,3=that,4=some@,5=mwe,6=@]{%%%
\mwe@lst@pop{#4#1}{#4#2}\expandafter\global%
\csname#6#5#6#4#3#6\mwe@some@bebl\endcsname}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
```

and this is `mwe.tex` wherefrom `mwe.pdf` results by `pdflatex -shell-escape mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass{./mwe}

\newenvironment{QUOTE}[1][1=.]{%
  \begin{quote}%
  \tiny\noindent
  \def\parQ{#1}``\ignorespaces
}{\parQ''%
  \end{quote}%
}

\begin{document}

MAIN TEXT: quotation

\begin{QUOTE}[~--~(\ldots, pp.~2).]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
... is mainly implemented by means of ... systems%
\end{QUOTE}

CONTINUES

\begin{table}[htb]
  \begin{center}\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|c|c|}
    \hline \multirow{4}{*}{1}          &&&& \\ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      & A text spanning on two rows     & May &          &  seven  \\
      &  and centered in four rows      &     & December &    7    \\
    &&&& \\ \hline %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \end{tabular}\end{center}
  \caption{Projected timelines}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Not just `QUOTE`, but all other environments are affected: `tabular` with left/right lines in the pattern `{|...|}` always adds two parallel unfinished lines to the left.

The `tabular` is affected when redefining `\begin/\end`, while `QUOTE` works with the latter redefines, but does not like the `\mwe@some@mark/\mwe@some@m@rk` expansions. I did not insert `mwe.ins` and `ltxdoc.cfg`. Thanks and appreciate if you look further on this. Sebastian

```
%%
%% This is file `mwe.cls',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% mwe.dtx  (with options: `class')
%% 
%% IMPORTANT NOTICE:
%% 
%% For the copyright see the source file.
%% 
%% Any modified versions of this file must be renamed
%% with new filenames distinct from mwe.cls.
%% 
%% For distribution of the original source see the terms
%% for copying and modification in the file mwe.dtx.
%% 
%% This generated file may be distributed as long as the
%% original source files, as listed above, are part of the
%% same distribution. (The sources need not necessarily be
%% in the same archive or directory.)
%%
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
%% Document class `mwe' to use with LaTeX 2e.
%%
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{./mwe}
[2013/03/29 v1.01
 MWE tex.stackexchange.com class]
\IfFileExists{suffix.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{suffix}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The suffix package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The suffix package allows for starred commands.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{tokenizer.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage[trim]{tokenizer}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The tokenizer package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%
    The tokenizer package allows list processing.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{xkvltxp.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{xkvltxp}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xkvltxp package was not found.}{%%%%%
    The xkvltxp package is bound to xkeyval.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{xkeyval.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{xkeyval}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xkeyval package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xkeyval package will anyway be loaded implicitly.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{xargs.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{xargs}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xargs package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xargs package is mandatory with commands and environments.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{xifthen.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{xifthen}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xifthen package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The xifthen package is needed for labels, references...%
  }}
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@nul[2][2=mwe@]{\mwe@lst@set{}{#1}[#2]}
\let\mwe@def@nul\mwe@lst@nul
\newcommandx%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mwe@lst@set[3][addprefix=\global,3=mwe@]{%%%%%%%%%%%
\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname#3#2\endcsname{#1}}
\let\mwe@def@set\mwe@lst@set
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@add[3][3=mwe@]{%
  \ifx\\#1\\\else\mwe@empt@if*{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{\@expandtwoargs%
    \mwe@lst@set{#1}{#2}[#3]}{\@expandtwoargs%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \mwe@lst@set{#1,\@nameuse{#3#2}}{#2}[#3]}\fi%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@rem[3][3=mwe@]{%
  \ifx\\#1\\\else\mwe@NOT@empt@if{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{%
    \mwe@lst@r@m{#1}{#2}[#3]}\fi%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@r@m[3][3=mwe@]{\@expandtwoargs%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \@removeelement{#1}{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{\mwe@v@r}\@expandtwoargs%
  \mwe@lst@set{\mwe@v@r}{#2}[#3]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@pop[3][3=mwe@]{%
  \mwe@empt@if*{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{%
    \mwe@def@nul{#1}[#3]}{\@expandtwoargs%%%%%%%%%%%
    \mwe@lst@p@p{\@nameuse{#3#2}}{,}\@expandtwoargs%
    \mwe@lst@r@m{\mwe@var}{#2}[#3]\@expandtwoargs%%%
    \mwe@def@set{\mwe@var}{#1}[#3]}%
}
\newcommand\mwe@lst@p@p[2]{\mwe@lst@get{#1#2}}
\newcommandx\mwe@lst@get[4]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[2=var,3=v@r,4=mwe@]{\GetTokens{#4#2}{#4#3}{#1}}
\newtest\mwe@empt@[1]{\equal{#1}{}}
\newcommand\utt@NOT@if[2]{\ifthenelse{#1}{}{#2}}
\newcommand\mwe@NOT@empt@if[2]{\mwe@NOT@if{\mwe@empt@{#1}}{#2}}
\newcommand\mwe@empt@if[2]{\mwe@empt@if*{#1}{#2}{}}
\WithSuffix%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\mwe@empt@if*[3]{\ifthenelse{\mwe@empt@{#1}}{#2}{#3}}
\LoadClass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}[2007/10/19]
\IfFileExists{fontenc.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The fontenc package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The fontenc package is required for some fonts.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{inputenc.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The inputenc package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%
    The inputenc package provides UTF-8 unicode.%
  }}
\IfFileExists{multirow.sty}{%
  \RequirePackage{multirow}}{%
  \ClassError{./mwe}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    The multirow package was not found.}{%%%%%%%%
    The multirow package is required for tables.%
  }}
\newif\if@mwe@some@that@\@mwe@some@that@false
\mwe@lst@nul{some@bels}
\mwe@def@nul{some@bebl}
\let\mwe@begin\begin
\def\begin{\mwe@some@mark\mwe@begin}
\let\mwe@end\end
\def\end{\mwe@some@m@rk\mwe@end}
\newcommandx\mwe@some@mark[7][1=true,2=bels%%%%%%%%
,3=that,4=some@,5=mwe,6=@,7=false]{\@expandtwoargs%
\mwe@lst@add{\if@mwe@some@that@#1\else#7\fi}{#4#2}%
\expandafter\global\csname#6#5#6#4#3#6#7\endcsname}
\newcommandx\mwe@some@m@rk[6]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[1=bebl,2=bels,3=that,4=some@,5=mwe,6=@]{%%%
\mwe@lst@pop{#4#1}{#4#2}\expandafter\global%
\csname#6#5#6#4#3#6\mwe@some@bebl\endcsname}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `mwe.cls'.
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `` \gdef\parQ{#1}\`\`\ignorespaces ``

Comment: i used a plain `\document{report}` MWE and it's no problem. please allow me a few days to track in my custom document class what is that causes this. (actually, all the answers improve the original, but the latter does not cause the extra space neither.) thank s.

Comment: it took me more than 10 days (well, the last two days mostly), sorry. there are two issues: (1) i redefine `\begin/\end`, (2) the commands `\mwe@some@mark/\mwe@some@m@rk` must have no expansion (i.e., `{}`)... in order that the spaces that are the subject of this post did not occur; other environments are affected by (1), e.g., tabular. thank s.

Comment: So you're redefining `\begin` and `\end`? I don't think it's something I want to tackle, sorry.

Comment: The culprit for the subject in question was `GetTokens`. I removed the dependency to `\RequirePackage[trim]{GetTokens}` by creating `LaTeX` code derived from it (or was it just the `trim` package option performing unexpectedly?). Well, `inparaenum` and `QUOTE` no longer insert spaces. Yet, `tabular` environments with format `{|c|...|}` commencing and closing with `\hline` are still having problems with two small bottom-left parallel vertical lines corresponding to the first two `|`s in the format. When `\begin` and `\end` are redefined (`\def`) without any hook, there are no extra lines.

Answer (score 3):

The "begin part" starts a paragraph, so the space after `\begin{QUOTE}` is not discarded.

```
\newenvironmentx{QUOTE}[1][1=.]{%
  \begin{quote}%
  \tiny\noindent
  \def\parQ{#1}``\ignorespaces
}{\parQ''%
  \end{quote}%
}
```

There's no need to say `\normalsize`, nor to use `\gdef`.

There's also no need to use `\newenvironmentx`:

```
\newenvironment{QUOTE}[1][.]{%
```

will do the same.